# Dynamically generating URL on multiple select boxes JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having two select boxes based on the user selection I am getting the initial URL and adding the extra bit from the second selection. My difficulty here is how can I get the second URL (dynamically calculated) and add 3rd bit of URL to it?

**Example:**

1. User select from the firstselect box "Bike" and url = www.google.com/
2. User select from the second select box "Bike2" and url becomes: www.google.com/bike2
3. User select from the third select box "Bike3" and url becomes: www.google.com/bike2/bike3

Working version of my ***"Two select boxes"*** can be found here: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4ao9ugho/)

The other option of Having ***"Three select boxes"*** can be found here: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lp9z3xep/4/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#basic_plan').change(function() {
    $('.second-select').hide();
    var an = $(this).val();
    switch (an) {
      case "ann":
        $('#jeeps').show();
        $('#cars-third-option').hide();
        $('#bikes-third-option').hide();
        $('#jeeps-third-option').hide();
        break;
      case "bi":
        $('#bikes').show();
        $('#cars-third-option').hide();
        $('#bikes-third-option').hide();
        $('#jeeps-third-option').hide();
        break;
      case "tri":
        $('#cars').show();
        $('#cars-third-option').hide();
        $('#bikes-third-option').hide();
        $('#jeeps-third-option').hide();
        break;
        /* and so on */
    }
  });

  $('#cars').change(function() {
    $('.third-select').hide();
    var an = $(this).val();
    switch (an) {
      case "1":
        $('#cars-third-option').show();
        $('#bikes-third-option').hide();
        $('#jeeps-third-option').hide();
        break;
      case "2":
        $('#cars-third-option').show();
        $('#bikes-third-option').hide();
        $('#jeeps-third-option').hide();
        break;
      case "3":
        $('#cars-third-option').show();
        $('#bikes-third-option').hide();
        $('#jeeps-third-option').hide();
        break;
        /* and so on */
    }
  });
  $('#bikes').change(function() {
    $('.third-select').hide();
    var an = $(this).val();
    switch (an) {
      case "1":
        $('#bikes-third-option').show();
        $('#cars-third-option').hide();
        $('#jeeps-third-option').hide();
        break;
      case "2":
        $('#bikes-third-option').show();
        $('#cars-third-option').hide();
        $('#jeeps-third-option').hide();
        break;
      case "3":
        $('#bikes-third-option').show();
        $('#cars-third-option').hide();
        $('#jeeps-third-option').hide();
        break;
        /* and so on */
    }
  });
  $('#jeeps').change(function() {
    $('.third-select').hide();
    var an = $(this).val();
    switch (an) {
      case "1":
        $('#jeeps-third-option').show();
        $('#cars-third-option').hide();
        $('#bikes-third-option').hide();
        break;
      case "2":
        $('#jeeps-third-option').show();
        $('#cars-third-option').hide();
        $('#bikes-third-option').hide();
        break;
      case "3":
        $('#jeeps-third-option').show();
        $('#cars-third-option').hide();
        $('#bikes-third-option').hide();
        break;
        /* and so on */
    }
  });

  $('#abc').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var anchorUrl = GetMainLink();
    window.open(anchorUrl, '_blank'); //open the link
  });


  function GetMainLink() {
    var mainSelection = $('#basic_plan').val();
    switch (mainSelection) {
      case "ann":
        return "www.google.com" + '/' + $('#jeeps').find('option:selected').text();
        break;
      case "bi":
        return "www.yahoo.com" + '/' + $('#bikes').find('option:selected').text();

        break;
      case "tri":
        return "www.bing.com" + '/' + $('#cars').find('option:selected').text();

        break;
        /* and so on */
    }
  }

});
```

```css
.second-select,
.third-select {
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-plans">
  <select id="basic_plan" name="bill_cycle">
    <option value="tri">Cars</option>
    <option value="bi">Bikes</option>
    <option value="ann">Jeeps</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <select id="cars" class="second-select">
    <option value="1">Car2</option>
    <option value="2">Car2</option>
    <option value="3">Car2</option>
  </select>
  <select id="bikes" class="second-select">
    <option value="1">Bike2</option>
    <option value="2">Bike2</option>
    <option value="3">Bike2</option>
  </select>
  <select id="jeeps" class="second-select">
    <option value="1">Jeep2</option>
    <option value="2">Jeep2</option>
    <option value="3">Jeep2</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <select id="cars-third-option" class="third-select">
    <option value="1">Car3</option>
    <option value="2">Car3</option>
    <option value="3">Car3</option>
  </select>
  <select id="bikes-third-option" class="third-select">
    <option value="1">Bike3</option>
    <option value="2">Bike3</option>
    <option value="3">Bike3</option>
  </select>
  <select id="jeeps-third-option" class="third-select">
    <option value="1">Jeep3</option>
    <option value="2">Jeep3</option>
    <option value="3">Jeep3</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="button-plans">
  <a id="abc" href="#"> Visit now </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated your code. Try this

```
$('#abc').on('click',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
    var anchorUrl = "www.bing.com/"+$("#basic_plan :selected").text();
    $("select[style='display: inline-block;'] :selected").each(function(index, element){
    anchorUrl += "/"+$(this).text()
    })
    console.log(anchorUrl);
  window.open(anchorUrl, '_blank'); //open the link
  });
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lp9z3xep/7/)

Comment: Hi John, check my JsFiddle link. Is that your requirement?

Comment: Just one small thing I've noticed If by default I want to use only the first two selections rahter than the 3rd as well it does not allow me. Can I change that?

Comment: you can choose first 2 drop down alone and click the "visit now" link. it will work. What error you are getting?

Comment: When you select Bikes>>Bike2>>BikeOption2 and click "Visit now" instead of www.bing.com/Bikes/BikeOption2 it comes as www.bing.com/Bikes/BikeOption2/Bike3

Comment: Coding  could you re-create the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107841/discussion-between-coding-and-john).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to store a global variable as empty string and then add every bit to it.

Example:

```
var url = "";

// Selectbox gets selected (first url)
url =  selectbox_val;  // url = "www.google.com";

// Second selection
url = url + "/"+ second_selectbox_val; // url = "www.google.com" + "/" + "param1";

// third selection
url = url + "/"+ third_selectbox_val; // url = "www.google.com/param1" + "/" + "param2";
```

The endresult would be `url = "www.google.com/param1/param2".`

No need to overcomplicate things :)

**with your code**

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
  var url = "";
  $('#basic_plan').change(function() {
    $('.second-select').hide();
    var an = $(this).val();
    url = url + "/" + $(this).text();
    switch (an) {
      case "ann":
        $('#jeeps').show();
        $('#cars-third-option').hide();
        $('#bikes-third-option').hide();
        $('#jeeps-third-option').hide();
        break;
      case "bi":
        $('#bikes').show();
        $('#cars-third-option').hide();
        $('#bikes-third-option').hide();
        $('#jeeps-third-option').hide();
        break;
      case "tri":
        $('#cars').show();
        $('#cars-third-option').hide();
        $('#bikes-third-option').hide();
        $('#jeeps-third-option').hide();
        break;
        /* and so on */
    }
  });

  $('#cars').change(function() {
    $('.third-select').hide();
    var an = $(this).val();
    url = url + "/" + $(this).text();
    switch (an) {
      case "1":
        $('#cars-third-option').show();
        $('#bikes-third-option').hide();
        $('#jeeps-third-option').hide();
        break;
      case "2":
        $('#cars-third-option').show();
        $('#bikes-third-option').hide();
        $('#jeeps-third-option').hide();
        break;
      case "3":
        $('#cars-third-option').show();
        $('#bikes-third-option').hide();
        $('#jeeps-third-option').hide();
        break;
        /* and so on */
    }
  });
  $('#bikes').change(function() {
    $('.third-select').hide();
    var an = $(this).val();
    url = url + "/" + $(this).text();
    switch (an) {
      case "1":
        $('#bikes-third-option').show();
        $('#cars-third-option').hide();
        $('#jeeps-third-option').hide();
        break;
      case "2":
        $('#bikes-third-option').show();
        $('#cars-third-option').hide();
        $('#jeeps-third-option').hide();
        break;
      case "3":
        $('#bikes-third-option').show();
        $('#cars-third-option').hide();
        $('#jeeps-third-option').hide();
        break;
        /* and so on */
    }
  });
  $('#jeeps').change(function() {
    $('.third-select').hide();
    var an = $(this).val();
    url = url + "/" + $(this).text();
    switch (an) {
      case "1":
        $('#jeeps-third-option').show();
        $('#cars-third-option').hide();
        $('#bikes-third-option').hide();
        break;
      case "2":
        $('#jeeps-third-option').show();
        $('#cars-third-option').hide();
        $('#bikes-third-option').hide();
        break;
      case "3":
        $('#jeeps-third-option').show();
        $('#cars-third-option').hide();
        $('#bikes-third-option').hide();
        break;
        /* and so on */
    }
  });

  $('#abc').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var anchorUrl = GetMainLink();
    url = anchorUrl + "/" + url;
    window.open(anchorUrl, '_blank'); //open the link
  });


  function GetMainLink() {
    var mainSelection = $('#basic_plan').val();
    switch (mainSelection) {
      case "ann":
        return "http://www.google.com" + '/' + $('#jeeps').find('option:selected').text();
        break;
      case "bi":
        return "http://www.yahoo.com" + '/' + $('#bikes').find('option:selected').text();

        break;
      case "tri":
        return "http://www.bing.com" + '/' + $('#cars').find('option:selected').text();

        break;
        /* and so on */
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: for me it does. Tell me whats wrong. What does the console say